# Why Phrogz multi-column sort doesn't work in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to use Phrogz's sorting, which would allow to sort by multiple columns:
http://phrogz.net/JS/Array.prototype.sortBy.js

In my case I'd like to sort by 3 columns:

1. Selection: the selected items should be on the top of the grid always
2. One property optionally selected by the user
3. Last name

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work well yet in my case. I wonder what I'm doing wrong. See jsFiddle demo for more details: http://jsfiddle.net/csabatoth/r7VWC/24/

```
self.sortPersons = function() {
    self.persons().sortBy(function(obj) {
        var sortCfgArray = [-obj.selected()];
        var srtIdx = self.sortIndex();
        if (srtIdx >= 0) {
            if (self.availCrit()[srtIdx].sortDir() === 0) {
                sortCfgArray.push(obj.properties[srtIdx])
            } else {
                sortCfgArray.push(-obj.properties[srtIdx])
            }
        }
        sortCfgArray.push(obj.lastname());
        return sortCfgArray;
    });
    self.persons.valueHasMutated();
    return true;
}
```

I suspect that I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the plugin or how you use it you just have two (minor) problems in your code:

- `ko.observable` and `ko.observableArray` are function where you can get the underlying value with calling them without any argument, so `obj.properties` should be `obj.properties()`
- your `obj.properties()` holds a collection of `PersonProperty` object where to get the value you need to call the `value` observable function

So the corrected `sortPersons` should look like:

```
self.sortPersons = function() {
    self.persons().sortBy(function(obj) {
        var sortCfgArray = [-obj.selected()];
        var srtIdx = self.sortIndex();
        if (srtIdx >= 0) {
            if (self.availCrit()[srtIdx].sortDir() === 0) {
                sortCfgArray.push(obj.properties()[srtIdx].value())
            } else {
                sortCfgArray.push(-obj.properties()[srtIdx].value())
            }
        }
        sortCfgArray.push(obj.lastname());
        return sortCfgArray;
    });
    self.persons.valueHasMutated();
    return true;
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFqvm/).